# What happens when the ActiveRecord ID overflows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I know this situation is an edge-case as 2,147,483,647 is a very large number, but I would like to know if ActiveRecord does anything special when the ID value overflows. The ID value seems to usually be defined as an integer, so I would imagine that there would be some kind of issue if new objects are created very quickly. This may not be an immediate problem, but if a system creates entries thousands of times per day or hour, it may become an issue in many years.

I have a bit of sample code to show what I'm talking about.

```
require "active_record"
require "pg"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: "postgresql",
  ...
)

ActiveRecord::Migration.suppress_messages do
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
    create_table :garbages
  end
end

class Garbage < ActiveRecord::Base; end
loop do
  Garbage.create
end
```

What will happen if I continue to let this run? What's the best solution for avoiding this kind of thing?

EDIT: Switched the example to postgresql, which uses 32-bit integers.

Comment: I thought sqlite integer primary keys were 64-bit, first of all, e.g., http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid. That's 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 entries, assuming zero deletions. In any case, if you're working with a system that'll create 2 billion entries, you'll likely run into performance problems before it rolls over, and if you anticipate this being an issue, you'd probably not be using an integer ID, no?

Comment: I was using sqlite3 for my example, but I was more thinking about postgresql which does have 32-bit entries.

Comment: I've voted to close this on the grounds that it is hypothetical. As with most hypothetical questions, the question is unlikely to actually help anybody.

Comment: @JonathanSternberg See [bigserial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html).

Comment: @coreyward The rest of my comments still apply, no?

Comment: I agree - by the time you could ever have this problem, you will be so fabulously wealthy from your massively successful website that you can pay a db engineer to solve it for you.

Comment: @MaxWilliams then let's say I'm the db engineer the massively successful person is paying. How would I solve it? I calculated how long it would take me to fill up the database (I was able to make 3,400 entries per second) and found I could do it in 7.5 days. I guess I could wait and figure out my answer in 7.5 days, but I thought I would ask here.

Comment: OK, the first step would be to switch the primary key field to a datatype allowing a much greater range of unique values: as @DaveNewton says, even the switch to 64 bit numbers would give you approx 10^18 values.  Before that ever filled up though you would have re-engineered to split your data into different databases, bypassing the problem completely but making your system more complex in other ways.  Also, spamming values into your database as fast as possible doesn't simulate anything other than you mucking about.  Get some proper work done :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't hypothetical at all, however it doesn't happen too often.

When you're int ID reaches the limits of Int32, you need to go to Int64. On SQL Server this is known as BIG_INT. on Postgres its bigint. I've had to use them twice. If you can overflow that....

Still, if sizing indicates that there might be a possibility that at some time in the future you might overflow int32, it will be easier to use bigint from the start. If you never need it, no problem. If you do, you're sorted and don't have to convert 21billion rows....